# .NET: XML Documentation - Assembly alias used in CREF tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml-comments, xml-documentation

I am having difficulty with resolving C# compiler warnings when using an assembly alias in a cref link. Unfortunately, the only feedback that I get from intellisense is 'Syntax error'. Here is an example of the link [see cref="global::Namespace.Class.Method"]. From what I can gather, the syntax is correct. The assembly being referenced has 'global' set for the alias.

Is this an issue with the compiler? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `global` has the same meaning in documentation comments as in normal code. It's just a *namespace alias* which allows you to avoid conflicts between namespace names and type names. See [MSDN on the Global Namespace Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) for more details.

Note that this *isn't* the same as [extern aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) which are used when you have two types with the same fully-qualified names, in different assemblies. Your question talking about "different roots" suggests you *might* be getting confused with extern aliases, but it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I was just editing my question after connecting those dots when you answered. I will take a look at the link you have provided.